# Tikz-cd commutative diagram not compiling?

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

Why is the following tikz-cd commutative diagram not compiling? It is giving me an error in the line `\mathbb{R} \arrow{ru}{\phi\circ E^{-1}}`.

```
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large, row sep=large]
    \mathcal{U}
     \arrow[swap]{d}{E}           
     \arrow{r}{\phi}  
&
    \mathbb{R} \arrow{ru}{\phi\circ E^{-1}}  \\     
%
    \mathcal{V}\subset\mathbb{R}^n
&
\end{tikzcd}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrows should be declared in the cell they start from.

I add a couple of tricks: the `\mathrlap` to pretend that `\subset\mathbb{R}` takes no space and the shift of the label in the diagonal arrow towards the target.

The “new” syntax for `\arrow` is much more flexible and liberal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large, row sep=large]
\mathcal{U} \arrow[d,swap,"E"] \arrow[r,"\phi"] &
\mathbb{R}
\\
\mathcal{V}\mathrlap{{}\subset\mathbb{R}^n}
  \arrow[ru,swap,"\phi\circ E^{-1}",pos=.75]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One arrow was not at the right place. I suppose this is more or less what you want:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd, amsmath, amssymb}%

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large, row sep=large]
    \mathcal{U}
     \arrow[swap]{d}{E}
 \arrow{r}{\phi}
& \mathbb{R} \\
  \mathcal{V}\subset\mathbb{R}^n \arrow[swap]{ru}{\phi\circ E^{-1}}
&
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]